# Getting who likes a youtube video

Tags: youtube-api

I would like to know if there is any way of getting who likes a video at youtube using the Youtube API. Does anybody if that is possible? Is there any endpoint available for this?

Comment: As far as I know, Youtube votes are anonymous

Answer (score 0):

U cant get the username who like it but all the nums of likes or dislikes, views o any info about the video, i made one easy library in js https://gist.github.com/lukasharing/9687807